# Unable to delete version of dataset in roboflow

Tags: roboflow

I can't delete a version of a dataset from roboflow. I click delete version, put in the name of the version, click **Delete version** but it doesn't work. It keeps spinning forever and the version is not deleted.

I created another account to troubleshoot this, and I can't remove a version on the other account as well.

Did anyone face similar issue? I added a screenshot.

[Delete version screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHbzp.png)

Thank you,

Jakub

Update:
I checked the console, it doesn't show any errors.
But I looked in the network tab and the response for the XHR request is:

**{"error":"You don't own that dataset."}**

Comment: I have seen a couple of people report this but haven’t been able to reproduce it or pin down the problem yet. Could you open your dev tools and post a screenshot of any messages in the console and then open the network tab and look for the XHR request to deleteVersion and post a screenshot of the Response tab?

Comment: Are there any extensions in your browser that might be interfering with javascript (for instance NoScript or adblockers)?

Answer (score 0):

First check the name by going to rename option, then copy that name enter into delete version name. It worked for me